# centos libjpeg error _imaging

Tags: python, libjpeg, python-imaging-library

I am trying to get my libjpeg working with python with little or no luck.

I have followed this tutorial to get it up and running http://blaolao.com/setting-up-django-mysql-mysql-python-pil-etc on my 10.6, worked like a charm

now that I am looking at getting this onto my server I am getting stuck

I believe it already had libjpeg 6.x.x on their and wanted to update

I downloaded libjpeg 8b,

> extracted ./configured sudo make sudo
>   make install

worked fine and actually says

> jpeg support available

then ran the Imaging installation, also worked fine.

now when i go into python and execute

> import _imaging

i get a traceback of

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can anybody help?

Comment: what distro do you use? it might be named slightly differently, e.g. in debian: python-imaging

Comment: i got the latest PIL 1.1.7 and libjpeg-8b

Answer (score 2):

I managed to CentOS working with a lot of the defaults.

I now have a running django app, with mod_wsgi, git, django-south, django-imagekit, rackspace CDN, apache, mysql etc.

I've found that there were so many people having issues with this, however all the answers only took me half-way, I have tracked what I have done and published all this info into a handy tutorial.

http://appelfreelance.com/2010/07/a-working-copy-django-pil-imaging-libjpeg-mysql-git-apache-mod_wsgi-easy_install-pip-django-imagekit-cdn-storage-on-centos-5-4/